# Why does for loop continuous infinite times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I run this code I expected the output will be `['a','a','e','e']`
but unexpectedly it runs continuously with out giving output.

```
v=['a','e']
for i in v:
    v.append(i)
print(v)
```

Comment: Because you keep adding `i` to `v` with `v.append(i)`?

Answer (score 1):

Because `v` gets bigger every iteration, there are several options to solve.

Iterate over a copy:

```
v = ['a', 'e']
for i in v[:]:  # slice notation to create a copy of v
    v.append(i)
print(v)
```

List comprehension:

```
v = ['a', 'e']
v += [i for i in v]
print(v)
```

Add operation:

```
v = ['a', 'e']
v += v
print(v)
```

Out:

```
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you append to a list you're iterating through, you extend the length of the list, letting it have more elements to loop through. Append to a new list instead:

```py
v = ['a', 'e']

new_v = []
for i in v:
    new_v += [i] * 2

print(new_v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration add new element to your list and then you get new element from list

```
k = 0
v=['a','e']
for i in v:
    v.append(i)
    print(len(v))
    if k == 10:
       break
    k+=1
print(v)
```

try this:

```
v = ['a', 'e']
for i in range(len(v)):
    v.append(v[i])
    
print(v)
```

or

```
v = ['a', 'e']
v = [i for _ in range(2) for i in v ]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a really interesting loop!
You better understand what's going on in the loop if you indent the `print()` call into the `for` loop:

```
v = ['a', 'e']
for i in v:
    v.append(i)
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'e', 'a']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'a']
```

As you can see, the first iteration of the `for` loop gives the
first element of the `v` list, which is `'a'`.
So `'a'` gets appended to the `v` list, and the output of `print(v)` is `['a', 'e', 'a']`.
Next, `'e'` gets appended to the list, so the output is `['a', 'e', 'a', 'e']`.

I believe that `['a', 'e', 'a', 'e']` is what you're trying to get frm the unindented `print()` call, and **here is how you can accomplish that with `list.copy()`**:

```
v = ['a', 'e']
for i in v.copy():
    v.append(i)
print(v)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'e', 'a', 'e']
```